# Is there any way so I can convert my given code to one line?

Tags: python, list

Here is the question:
Define a function named `convert` that takes a list of numbers as its only parameter and returns a list of each number converted to a string.

For example, the call `convert([1, 2, 3])` should return `["1", "2", "3"]`.

And this is my code:

```
def convert(li):
    for i in range(len(li)): li[i] = str(li[i])
    return li
```

But this will give me error as another line is used.
How do i convert the code to one line?

Comment: `range(len(...))` is a typical anti-pattern in Python. There's nearly always a better way.

Comment: "But this will give me error as another line is used." What are you talking about? When I try your code, there is no error, and there is no reason why you should have to put the code on one line.

Comment: Dude it is a challenge type so i just have to use a single line for the questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick list comprehension to do this in a line.

```
def convert(li):
    # For each item in the list, convert the integer to string:
    print([str(i) for i in li]) 

convert([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
convert = lambda li: list(map(str, li))
```

or a list comprehension:

```
convert = lambda li: [str(e) for e in li]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer this solution:

```
def convert(li):
    return list(map(str, li))
```